# How to add a button next to the text that will render next to each item in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, android-studio

I am trying to add a button that will render next to each list item, but i am struggling on how to do that.

```
 return (

  <View>

  <Text style={styles.Blue}>My List</Text>

    <FlatList
    data={this.state.ListData}
    renderItem={({item}) =>


    <Text style={styles.myText}>{item.item_name}</Text>}

    keyExtractor={({id},index) => id}


    />

  </View>

  );
```

Comment: Where is the `Button`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding like below hope this helps. feel free for doubts

```
<FlatList
        data={this.state.ListData}
        renderItem={({item}) =>{
    return(
    <>
     <Text style={styles.myText}>{item.item_name}</Text>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.buttonPress}><Text>Button</Text></TouchableOpacity>
    </>
    )
    }


       }

        keyExtractor={({id},index) => id}


        />
```

Comment: Thank you very much.